# SQL Server Lag () with condition to calculate previous working day

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powerbi, dax

I have looked around StackOverflow but no-one offers the solution I need.

I have a date table:

```
TheDate ItalyWorkingDay
2039-12-28  1
2039-12-27  1
2039-12-26  0
2039-12-25  0
2039-12-24  0
2039-12-23  1
2039-12-22  1
2039-12-21  1
```

and I have to calculate the previous working date for every day:

```
TheDate ItalyWorkingDay PrevItWorkDay
2039-12-28  1   2039-12-27
2039-12-27  1   2039-12-23
2039-12-26  0   2039-12-23
2039-12-25  0   2039-12-23
2039-12-24  0   2039-12-23
2039-12-23  1   2039-12-22
2039-12-22  1   2039-12-21
2039-12-21  1   2039-12-20
```

I spent the whole working day trying to figure it out both in dax and in SQL but I could not.

A solution in dax or in T-SQL would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method would be to use `APPLY` to get the previous row:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(date,'2039-12-28'),1),
            (CONVERT(date,'2039-12-27'),1),
            (CONVERT(date,'2039-12-26'),0),
            (CONVERT(date,'2039-12-25'),0),
            (CONVERT(date,'2039-12-24'),0),
            (CONVERT(date,'2039-12-23'),1),
            (CONVERT(date,'2039-12-22'),1),
            (CONVERT(date,'2039-12-21'),1))V(TheDate,ItalyWorkingDay);
GO


SELECT YT.TheDate,
       YT.ItalyWorkingDay,
       PD.TheDate AS PrevItWorkDay
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) oa.TheDate
                  FROM dbo.YourTable oa
                  WHERE oa.TheDate < YT.TheDate
                    AND oa.ItalyWorkingDay = 1
                  ORDER BY oa.TheDate DESC) PD
ORDER BY YT.TheDate DESC;
```

On SQL Server 2022+ you could use `LAG` and its `IGNORE NULLS` feature:

```sql
SELECT YT.TheDate,
       YT.ItalyWorkingDay,
       LAG(CASE YT.ItalyWorkingDay WHEN 1 THEN YT.TheDate END) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY YT.TheDate) AS PrevItWorkDay
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
ORDER BY YT.TheDate DESC;
```

Or you could use a gaps an island solution, which works on SQL Server 2012+:

```sql
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT YT.TheDate,
           YT.ItalyWorkingDay,
           SUM(ItalyWorkingDay) OVER (ORDER BY TheDate
                                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Grp
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT),
WorkingDates AS(
    SELECT G.TheDate,
           G.ItalyWorkingDay,
           MAX(CASE G.ItalyWorkingDay WHEN 1 THEN G.TheDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY G.Grp) AS WorkingDate
    FROM Grps G)
SELECT WD.TheDate,
       WD.ItalyWorkingDay,
       LAG(WD.WorkingDate) OVER (ORDER BY WD.TheDate) AS PrevItWorkDay
FROM WorkingDates WD;
```

Note all solutions here return `NULL` for `2039-12-21` as the date `2039-12-20` does not exist in your data, and thus it is unknown if it is a working day or not. I *assume* your actual (calendar) table has the date in it.

*Clean up:*

```
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FH5S5TEK)

Comment: Since you're aggregating the same column that you are ordering by, you can leverage the fact that `MAX/MIN` already ignore nulls and make window functions work in versions pre-2022 as well, https://dbfiddle.uk/9wJ80VRI I doubt this offers any tangible performance benefits (if any at all) over the solutions suggested but thought it worth adding as an alternative solution

Comment: Yeah, there's multiple different routes, these were just a few my "mind" went to, @GarethD . The windowed `MAX` is another nice solution.

Comment: The `LAG...IGNORE NULLS` and your windowed `MAX` solution also result in the same [execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MltJB.png).